# What is the difference between SHIFA'ah and SHAFA'ah?

Tags: arabic, dua, terminology, shafaah

I want to know the exact meaning and difference between *SHIFA'ah* and *SHAFA'ah* and which one we need to ask Allah for?

Comment: شفاعة شَفاعة Shafa'ah (with a fatha) is the only word that really exists as there is no Shifa'ah with a "kasra" in Arabic AFAIK, so Shifa'ah is simply a wrong transliteration! So i guess Shifa'/Shefa' شِفَاء=healing, recovery is the other word you may mean! And you could ask for both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Arabic, words are made up of 2 or more consonant letters, collectively called as Root Words.

Vowels are changed to express tenses.

So,

SHIFA'ah=interceding

SHAFA'ah=intercede

and hence mean the same.

The second part of the question is answered by Andre and I support it.

> You want Allah's mercy to intercede on your behalf and forgive you for the sins you are regretful for.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Well i would like to know where you got the Shifa'ah from? if you refer to شفاعة then the transliteration of the verb and noun would both be about the same shafa'a شفَعَ or shafa'ah شَفاعة.

Answer (score 2):

Actually

> شفاعة

means intersession. **Intersession** is when someone intercedes/intervenes on your behalf.

So you should ask Allah for **SHAFA'ah** as well. You want Allah's mercy to intercede on your behalf and forgive you for the sins you are regretful for.

We can also ask Allah for the intercession of the Prophet and the great Saints (such as the family of the prophet).

For example people make a prayer such as this"

> **By the Right of Muhammad and His Pure household, Oh Allah please forgive me, my parents and my family!**

**This is called Intercession, Tavassol, Shafaat.**

Answer (score 0):

Shifa  is Allah's  intercession / permission for the granting of a healing or Allah's  will grant whom he wills the permission to intercede for the forgiveness of our sins as stated in the  Versee of the Throne " none shall intercede for you save by Allah's permission". So in my mind shifat / Shafat (I agree the similarity as commented in a prior answer)  would have two contexts 1) for intercession for healing from physical sickness and 2) intercession for the the forgiveness of sins you acknowledge or are aware or unaware commited yourself current disbelief in Allah or ascribing partners to Allah who knows and guides best!

Comment: As with the difference of the two words I agree with prior answer that they have a similar meaning placed in the two contexts. My source is Quran Verse of the throne and my understanding. Correction on typo on my prior comment above "healing from physical sickness".

Answer (score -1):

Shifa means "good health"

Shafa means "corner, death, deep grave"

So you should ask for shifa from Allah. Allah knows what's going on in your head and heart, so if you are asking for good health but due to lack of knowledge you use the word Shafa (as actions are based on intention) I don't think you need to worry as your intention was to ask for good health. Allah knows best.